# Azure Service Bus Queue, Topics and Relays

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-queues

I am preparing for Microsoft 70-532 exam and got stuck with following question:

You are developing a messaging solution to integrate two applications named WeatherSummary and WeatherDetails. The WeatherSummary
application displays a summary of weather information for major cities. The WeatherDetails application displays weather details for a specific city.
You need to ensure that the WeatherDetails application displays the weather details for the city that the user selects in the WeatherSummary
application.
What should you do?

A. Create an Azure Service Bus Queue communication. In the WeatherDetails application, implement the PeekLock method.

B. Create an Azure Service Bus Topics object. In the WeatherDetails application, create a filter.

C. Create an Azure Service Bus Relay object. In the WeatherDetails application, create a filter.

D. Create an Azure Service Bus Queue communication. In the WeatherDetails application, implement the ReceiveAndDelete method.

I am confusing whether we should use Topics or Relay in this scenario and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with B since it mentions the use of a Topic. You could have the detail application publish weather changes for each city on the topic and the summary application could subscribe to cities of interest, by using a filter.